# Apply corretion formula to each channel for 5D image

Tags: java, groovy, imagej, imagej-macro

I'm completely new to groovy and have only limited experience in writing ImageJ macros, so this might be a really easy problem to fix, but here goes:

I have a 5D hyperstack (3 channels, 3 slices, ~100 stage positions) which suffer from a highly uneven illumination. I have found a rather straightforward formula for correcting for this. The formula is

[image: C = (R-D)*m/(F-D)]

where C is the corrected image, R is the raw image, D is the dark-field image, F is the flat-field image and m is the image-averaged value of (F-D).

For single-channel 3D images (x, y, p) this is relatively straight-forward and does not need any macro scripting, but for multi-channel, multi-slice 5D images, I would have to at the very least split the image into individual channels before I can apply the correction formula to each channel and then recombine them. I have been trying to write a macro using groovy to handle this for me (I chose groovy because I was told it was more user-friendly, so I'm open to other suggestions), but I can't seem to get it running. Currently, I have the code below (I left out the dark-field because my images are already corrected for this during acquisition):

```
import ij.*
import ij.plugin.filter.ImageMath
import ij.process.*
import ij.gui.*
import java.awt.*
import ij.plugin.*

class My_Plugin implements PlugIn {

    void run(java.lang.String arg) {
        ImagePlus flatfield = WindowManager.getImage("flatfield.tif")
        ImagePlus rawstack = WindowManager.getImage("Untitled.tif")
        ImagePlus correctedstack = IJ.createImage("HyperStack", "32-bit composite-mode", 512, 512, 3, rawstack.z, 1)
        float m;
        for (c in flatfield.c) {
            flatfield.setC(c)
            rawstack.setC(c)
            correctedstack.setC(c)
            m = flatfield.getStatistics().mean
            rawstack.z.each { z ->
                rawstack.setZ(z)
                correctedstack.setZ(z)
                if (m > 0) {
                    rawstack.processor.multiply(m)
                    correctedstack.processor.divide(flatfield)
                }
            }
        }
        correctedstack.show()
    }

}

new My_Plugin().run()
```

This code currently fails with the following exception (but I suspect the code itself is generally poorly written):

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ij.process.FloatProcessor.divide() is applicable for argument types: (ij.CompositeImage) values: [img["flatfield.tif" (-274), 8-bit, 512x512x3x3x1]] Possible solutions: dilate(), dilate(), erode(), erode(), find(), noise(double)`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can just explain the Groovy error you encounter, not how to fix your implementation of the correction formula. It says that FloatProcessor doesn't have a method with the below signature. Neither its own nor inherited nor through other Groovy mechanics, e.g. MOP, AST or Extensions

```
divide(ij.CompositeImage img)
```

The ImageJ's source code confirms that neither [FloatProcessor](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/a3918aafc12ae783a5690c751de98851bf95a059/ij/process/FloatProcessor.java) nor its superclass [ImageProcessor](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/a3918aafc12ae783a5690c751de98851bf95a059/ij/process/ImageProcessor.java) don't have such a method.